# resigning the keyboard swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift

So I just updated to swift 1.2 and now my code to resign the keyboard wont work?

the code is:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches:NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

the error says Overriding method with selector "touchesBegan:withEvent:" has incompatible type

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `NSSet` with `Set<NSObject>`

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

The syntax has been edited in swift 1.2. The `NSSet` was replaced by `Set<NSObject>`

See the [Blog Post](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=22) and the [Xcode 6.3 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html)